# Implementing workflow to an enterprise application

Tags: workflows, enterprise-architecture, wcf, workflow-foundation

We are a few developers develoing an enterprise project includes several modules and approximately 200 UI resources for
our company. Project will be written/programmed in Asp.NET MVC, WCF services for each module, and layered structure adhering to
design pattern pirinciples and within the scope of an enterprise application constraints. What we have been asked is to develop and
implement a workflow structure include an activity designer and the core -state machine, locking and ownership, automated actions, 
specific workers for actions etc.

I am new to workflow development and implementation to an enterprise project, since a couple of days, i have dug into this, 
passing through an R&D stage. In fact, i had an experience at my ex-company on creating and handling the processes of workflow through an
activity designer tool embedded in the application, but i never been at the development side, i've just used as a consumer.
So it hasn't any affect on development knowledge.

I need help on what to do to achieve this in a short time period.

**Options**

1- Quick courses on workflow concept, building activity designer tools ([BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation)), writing the whole code, testing and implementing, Shortly, do it yourself

2-Buy/Use a workflow tool and implement to your project.

3-Other ways that i am still not aware :)

So far, I ve found [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301733/building-workflow-driven-applications) closest to mine in SE. It doesn't help so much. And i was researching for [WF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation), i decided to take some courses on this as a preliminary. The latest up to date WF course at Pluralsight(Microsoft) is on 2010! I didn't sort out if WF is loosing its popularity or the plug is being pulled.

Well, we are confused on where to start and what to do, we keep researching, we need a real experienced guidance on this.

Comment: My experience with workflow tools: run away. Just build your system as a normal thing without the buzzword tooling, you can implement workflow processes to your specific requirements much cheaper and easier without using those tools.

Comment: Thank you @gbjbaanb. As a developer, i am keen on building this on my own, but i was wondering wf tools on the stores. Well, if we build this with our own code, should we stick to windows workflow foundation?

Comment: I don't know anyone who uses WF now, I wouldn't. I'd roll my own. MS doesn't really pull the plug on anything, they just don't get any development - and I think WF is in this category along with Silverlight and suchlike.  The only people I know who used Biztalk now spit feathers at maintaining it.